# Why do I get a "read-only file system" error when I scp an EC2 directory?

Tags: amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying to download a directory from an EC2 instance like this:

> scp -i key.pem -r ubuntu@123.456.789:/dir/DIR/ /

but get a "/DIR: read-only file system" error.

I tried moving the directory to /home/ubuntu and running the command again on the new location, but still receive the same error.

I get the same error when I chmod 777 the directory first.

What could be causing this?